# Can't open applications menu

Tags: release-freya, slingshot

The applications menu in the top left corner of the screen will not open: if clicked nothing happens, the hotkey also does not work.

I am on elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya (64-bit) Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-4500U.

Comment: Are there any messages? Do the indicators work? The dock at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 12):

I've encountered this problem before: it's caused by slingshot crashing while backgrounded. There is a very easy way to fix it.

Open a terminal, either from plank or by using the shortcut [super] + [T] and enter:

`pkill slingshot`

The next time you click the applications indicator slingshot will restart and work as normal.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly. However this is a recurring problem for me... Any idea why this keeps happening? A recent update perhaps?